# Selected text remove element already wrapped in a span

Tags: javascript, textselection, getselection

I have a scenario/dilemma, I am a little stuck trying to figure out.  Below will be my best of a visual representation.

**1. I select**

This is dummy `text to select`

**2. I bold and it gets wrapped with a span**

This is dummy **text to select**

```
<h2 This is dummy <span style="font-weight: 700;">text to select</span></h2>
```

**3. Now lets say I want to select some text but we know it's already wrapped in a span**

This is `dummy [BOLD]text[BOLD]` **to select**

**4. Its a crossover with selected text, so now my code.  In my important comment, I can identify that the element is found in the selection. But how can I find it and then remove the span.**

```
const el = document.createElement('span');

  function handleNodeWrap(){
    if(selection?.containsNode(el,true)){
      //! IMPORTANT find and remove element of selected text
    }
    surroundSelection(el);
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Here's one approach to remove the span from the selected text:**

```
const el = document.createElement('span');

function handleNodeWrap() {
  if (selection?.containsNode(el, true)) {
    // find parent node of the selected text
    let parentNode = selection.anchorNode.parentNode;
    // create a new range that selects the entire content of the parent node
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNodeContents(parentNode);
    // replace the content of the parent node with the plain text version
    let text = range.extractContents().textContent;
    parentNode.textContent = text;
  } else {
    surroundSelection(el);
  }
}
```